# How to arrange wells in bootstrap in two different columns?

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to arrange my list of wells to be in two different columns. I have attached my plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/35oC9Eochk6EPgKeI9he?p=preview.

This is my view

```
  <div class="well well-lg" ng-repeat="(key, data) in myData.config.A" style="width:500px;">{{key}}</div>
        </div>
```

This is my controller

```
$scope.myData={
  "_id": "ui",
  "config": {
    "A": {
      "aaaa": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      },
      "bbbbb": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      },
      "ccccc": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": false
      },
      "ddddd": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      },
      "eeeee": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      },
      "fffff": {
        "required": true,
        "editable": true
      }
    }
  }
}  
});
```

I want aaaa,bbbb,cccc in one column and ddddd,eeee,fffff in another column. How to arrange these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way I can think of doing it by using Boostrap's Grid System `row.column`.

The `ng-repeat` is tracked by `$index`. From there, you can specify which data you want to display selectively by using `ng-show`. This way you can display it in two columns.

**Here is the plunker link:**

[Updated Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/nEYuTo4RgzqnpIgLJMGK?p=preview)

**NOTE:** As an alternative you can use something other than the bootstrap grid system if you want to customise your own columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 columns use one of `col-xs-6`, `col-sm-6`, `col-md-6` or `col-lg-6`classes inside the `class` attribute of your iterated element

like so:

```
<div class="well well-lg col-xs-6" ng-repeat="(key, data) in myData.config.A" style="width:500px;">{{key}}</div>
```

But you wouldn't be able to sort them as you would want because key/value entries in objects are not ordered, when you iterate them using a key+value `ng-repeat`, you can't assure an order, even when you think you can, different implementations of JavaScript engines may iterate over them differently.
If you would like them ordered as you described, the simplest approach would be to use a array and have them sorted/shuffled as you want.

like: `['aaaa', 'ddddd', 'bbbb' .......]`

```
<div class="well well-lg col-xs-6" ng-repeat="data in myData" style="width:500px;">{{data }}</div>
```